# Unlock the DLC in Dragon Quest IX by connecting to a friend

Tags: nintendo-ds, dragon-quest-ix

Now that the Nintendo Wi-Fi for Nintendo DS is unavailable, is it true that if I connect to a friend that already has the DLC unlocked, will I be able to unlock it after we play? Do we need to do something in order to unlock the DLC on my cartridge? I want to know since I want to have everything in the game, also, I just started the game recently, will the option to connect to a friend unlock in some specific point on the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reddit thread should tell you what you need to know:
https://www.reddit.com/r/dragonquest/comments/65o3zo/how_to_unlock_the_dlc_for_dragon_quest_9_in_2017/

> What you need. A copy of Dragon Quest 9 [https://www.amazon.com/Dragon-Quest-IX-Sentinels-Nintendo-DS/dp/B002I0EH6I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002I0EH6I) A computer with USB ports and access to the Internet. The Dragon Quest 9 save editor http://www.woodus.com/den/games/dq9ds/save_editor.php A DS save dongle [https://www.amazon.com/NDS-Adapter-Plus-Nintendo-Windows-Pc/dp/B00XVO0I36](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00XVO0I36) http://www.nds-card.com/ProShow.asp?ProID=440
>
> Step 1 Download the Dragon Quest 9 save editor and buy a DS save dongle. Step 2 Plug your Dragon Quest 9 cart into your PC using your DS save dongle. Step 3 open the Dragon Quest 9 save editor and follow this guide https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/71126194 Step 4 play the DLC :)

Comment: Another option is to go outside and run around for a bit, avoiding this problem forever :D

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. while the link answers the question it's always a good idea to quote the relevant sections as if the link was to become unaccessible then you're answer wont be useful anymore